# ubuntu doest not boot after installation of window 8

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I had Ubuntu 12.04 , then I installed window 8 in another partition on my system. after installing win8 , my system is not able to boot to Ubuntu. that is when I start my system it boots to win8. i lost my access to Ubuntu , if anyone can help me please.

Comment: See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

The [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) utility should be your best best to fix this issue.

To use it, you can either:

- download and boot on a [Boot-Repair-Disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)-**64bit**
- or boot on a Ubuntu-64bit disk, then install Boot-Repair in it

[image]